# vba word 2007 - protect document but enable toolbars

Tags: vba, word-2007

I have a document with sections that are protected and unprotected. With Word 2003 the sections that were unprotected had formatting enabled - specifically the bullets and numbering. Now with Word 2007, even though the same sections are unprotected, the bulleting and numbering is disabled. Is there anyway to enable this? 
I tried playing around with CommandBars but nothing has worked.
e.g. Application.CommandBars("Formatting").Enabled = True

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent chance that any code you wrote re: office 2003 is going to behave differently in 2007 as far as things like "CommandBars" goes.  The rule of thumb I'm currently using is that if Office 2007 uses a different UI to handle it, then the API for the function has changes too.

I would try the [Protect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.protect.aspx), not the CommandBars object.  There is a *EnforceStyleLock* parameter which may help.